# Perl noob, undefined subroutine?

Tags: perl

I'm making a simple perl script which checks if the url is up, you can check websites via a txt file. So my text file is list.txt and on the first line it contains https://google.com. That's it pretty simple script, but when I try to run it gives me this error? `Undefined subroutine &main::head called at test.pl line 7.` 
And here is the code of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;

system(($^O eq 'MSWin32') ? 'cls' :'clear');

head();

my $usage = " \nperl $0 <list.txt>\n perl $0 lista.txt";
die "$usage" unless $ARGV[0];

open(tarrget,"<$ARGV[0]") or die "$!";
while(<tarrget>){
chomp($_);
$target = $_;

my $path = "/";

print "\nTarget --> $target\n";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 });
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like           Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31");
my $req = $ua->get("$target/$path");
if($req->is_success) {
print "\n  [!] Yay website works! \n \n"; } }
```

How do I make this script work?

Comment: You're calling a function, `head`, for which you haven't provided a definition. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What is `head()` supposed to do? Where is it defined?

Comment: You have written far too much code without testing it. In Perl, as much as in any language, you should write two or three lines at the most before testing, and only write more when you know you have a firm foundation.

Answer (score 3):

This error specifically means - there is a function called `head` - that you're calling on line 7. 
And it doesn't exist.

No one else can figure out what it's supposed to do either. The fact you've got it there implies you've copied your code from somewhere - ask them.

I will offer a piece of advice though - ALWAYS turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the start of a piece of code.

It looks quite a bit like this code is simply trying to run through a list of URLs and test whether they're retrievable. But it's doing a few things that are poor style at best (and just won't work at worst):

- No strict/warnings.
- `open` should really be `open ( my $target_list, "<", $ARGV[0] );`.
- You've got `$path` of `/` which you're sticking on the end of `$target` to make `$target//`.
- install `perltidy` and use it to reformat your code. Trust me, this makes life easier in the long run.
- don't create a new useragent each iteration of the loop. It's redundant.

With these things in place, your code might look a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;

unless ( $filename and -f $filename ) {
    print "Usage: $0 <filename>\n";
    exit;
}

my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new( ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 0 } );
$useragent->timeout(10);
$useragent->agent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31"
);

open( my $target_file, "<", $filename ) or die $!;
while ( my $target = <$target_file> ) {
    chomp($target);
    print "Fetching $target\n";
    my $request = $useragent->get("$target/");
    if ( $request->is_success ) {
        print "\n  [!] Yay website works! ($target)\n \n";
    }
}
close($target_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

A short-term fix would appear to be to remove the call to the undefined `head()` subroutine. It doesn't seem to be doing anything useful and (as you haven't defined it) it is causing your program to die.

In the longer term you should probably work out why that call was there and define the correct subroutine.